# .NET fulltext autocomplete in a combobox. Any performance-positive way of overriding listitems?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, combobox, full-text-search

I'm struggling to meet a demand from my supervisors. I really hope that someone could give some advice.
Basically there are places in our project where there is a big selection of options. The most concrete example is choosing a city in the world. The items are hundreds of thousands. 
Using standard winforms controls and properties, one can search through a list fast.
The problem is that we're using a concatenation of city&district name for all the items. Essentially PREFIX autotomplete works but does not work as needed. The task is to filter and show items by any given string in any part of the item. Essentially a FULL TEXT search in the combobox.
Does anyone have an idea about switching autocomplete sources in runtime relatively qiuckly and handling the suggest/suggestappend event? 
Also the project is in VB.NET, though any form of .NET advice will be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

UPDATE: The latest attempt using [competent_tech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002323/competent-tech)'s suggestion with some minor modifications.

```
Imports System.Data
Public Class Form1
Private _ErrorText As String
Private _CommandExecuted As Boolean

Private m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete As Boolean
Private m_sLastSearchedFor As String = ""

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call Me.SetStatusText("Loading...")
    Me._ErrorText = ""
    Me.Cities.Clear()
    Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Try
        Me._CommandExecuted = True
        Me.Ara_airportsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Cities.ara_airports)
    Catch ex As Exception
        _ErrorText = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If Me._ErrorText = "" Then
        Me.SetStatusText(Me.Cities.ara_airports.Count & " Records loaded")
    Else
        Me.SetStatusText(Me._ErrorText)
    End If
    Me.BindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
End Sub

Private Sub SetStatusText(ByVal sText As String)
    Me.Text = sText
End Sub

Private Sub cboPort_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles cboPort.KeyDown
    Try
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete = False
        Else
            m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete = True
        End If
    Catch theException As Exception
        ' ...
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub cboPort_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboPort.KeyUp
    Try
        If m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete Then
            With cboPort
                If .Text.Length >= 2 Then
                    Dim cSuggestions As IList
                    Dim sError As String = ""

                    m_sLastSearchedFor = .Text

                    cSuggestions = GetSuggestions(m_sLastSearchedFor)
                    .DataSource = Nothing
                    If cSuggestions IsNot Nothing Then
                        .BindingContext = New BindingContext
                        .DisplayMember = "CName"
                        .ValueMember = "id"
                        .DataSource = New BindingSource(cSuggestions, Nothing)

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
                        .DroppedDown = True
                        .Text = m_sLastSearchedFor
                        If .Text.Length > 0 Then .SelectionStart = .Text.Length
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Catch theException As Exception
        ' ...
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function GetSuggestions(ByVal searchFor As String) As IList
    BindingSource.Filter = "CName LIKE '%" & searchFor & "%'"
    Return BindingSource.List
End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we address this with very large sets of data (full set of drug information) is:

1) Handle the combo's TextChanged event

2) Within this event, get the list of suggestions that match the user's current input from the database. We leverage the power of database searching to find matches anywhere within the string.

3) When the suggestions are retrieved, bind them to the combobox

4) Wait for a little bit (500ms) to let the UI catch up (we use a combination of System.Threading.Thread.Sleep and System.Windows.Format.Application.DoEvents()).

A couple of notes on this approach:

1) Nothing is bound to the list when the form is first opened

2) We wait until the user has entered at least 4 characters before we start searching to reduce the hit on the DB and improve the user experience (you don't want to show all of the matches for A, for example).

**Update with code to show full solution:**

Here are some additional notes and code to show the actual process.

The ComboBox should be configured with all of the properties set to their default values with the exception of:

```
AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend
PreferredDropDownSize = 0, 0
```

Here is the code that we use for our specific situation (searching first four chars) with a placeholder for retrieving and assigning the data:

```
Private m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete As Boolean
Private m_sLastSearchedFor As String = ""

Private Sub cboName_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles cboName.KeyDown
    Try
        ' Catch up and down arrows, and don't change text box if these keys are pressed.
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete = False
        Else
            m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete = True
        End If
    Catch theException As Exception
        ' Do something with the error
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub cboName_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboName.TextChanged
    Try
        If m_fOkToUpdateAutoComplete Then
            With cboName
                If .Text.Length >= 4 Then
                    ' Only do a search when the first 4 characters have changed
                    If Not .Text.Substring(0, 4).Equals(m_sLastSearchedFor, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                        Dim cSuggestions As IEnumerable
                        Dim sError As String = ""

                        ' Record the last 4 characters we searched for
                        m_sLastSearchedFor = .Text.Substring(0, 4)

                        ' And search for those
                        cSuggestions = GetSomeSuggestions(m_sLastSearchedFor) ' Your code here
                        .DataSource = Nothing
                        If cSuggestions IsNot Nothing Then
                            ' Because this can use the same data source as the list, ensure that
                            ' the bindingcontexts are different so that the lists are not tied to each other
                            .BindingContext = New BindingContext

                            .DataSource = cSuggestions

                            ' Let the UI process the results
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
                            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_sLastSearchedFor) Then
                        ' Clear the last searched for text
                        m_sLastSearchedFor = ""
                        cboName.DataSource = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Catch theException As Exception
        ' Do something with the error
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Basically we have:
ABC/prefix/ - Name of item
...
and there are about 15000 items.
The requested solution is that on any keystroke the items are filtered by that keystroke "WITH NO DELAY".
I know that there are limitations but it seemed to me that it was a good solution/relatively what you describe/.
Unfortunately the process should be "FASTER", because "WHEN YOU HIT A KEY IN EXCEL IT GIVES YOU INSTANT RESULTS". 
I know that doesn't sound right, but....
Still working on switching list items of the control on keypress but it's not working "APPROPRIATELY"!
Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Oh no, you're working with MY users! I'm surprised they didn't ask for it to predict what they really wanted. But seriously, the outline above should do exactly what you want. The TextChanged event is fired on keystrokes and you can rebind the combobox directly in that event as long as you call DoEvents to let the UI catch up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again!:) Unfortunately most of my user are my bosses so... Anyway I've read your suggestion again and I've tried it but to no avail. The issue is similar to switching autocomplete list at any point. When binding the control it resets and thus text is set to nothing. It's similar with autocomplete. When changing lists the autocomplete list closes and expects another char to start querying again and so it enters an unusable loop. Still looking! :(

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer with some settings that you should check on the combobox and the code that we use for our situation. Hopefully this will get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again!
I've tried your suggestion and modified it a bit and it's a success!
PreferredDropDownSize is not in the MS stock control set but it turned out not be a deal-breaker. I still have to make some minor modification in text selection event but it's a really good answer!
Thanks for your help!

P.S. I've updated the question with my latest attempt.

Comment: Not a problem. If this solves your issue, can you check the checkbox next to the answer so that future visitors to this question will know that this resolved the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Oops!
Sorry about that!
Just got out of my mind.
Thanks again!